# RPM build errors File listed twice

Tags: php, rpmbuild

I'm trying to build an rpm of the latest stable php (5.6.7) under CentOS 7.

And when I try to build it, I'm getting the following errors:

```
[bluethundr@repo SPECS]$ rpmbuild -ba php.spec
Processing files: php-5.6.7-1.el7.x86_64
warning: File listed twice: /etc/rc.d/init.d/php-fpm
error: Symlink points to BuildRoot: /usr/bin/phar ->     /home/bluethundr/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/php-5.6.7-1.el7.x86_64/usr/bin/phar.phar
warning: File listed twice: /usr/share/man/man1/php-cgi.1.gz
warning: File listed twice: /usr/share/man/man1/php-config.1.gz
warning: File listed twice: /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
warning: File listed twice: /usr/share/man/man1/phpize.1.gz

RPM build errors:
    File listed twice: /etc/rc.d/init.d/php-fpm
    Symlink points to BuildRoot: /usr/bin/phar ->     /home/bluethundr/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/php-5.6.7-1.el7.x86_64/usr/bin/phar.phar
    File listed twice: /usr/share/man/man1/php-cgi.1.gz
    File listed twice: /usr/share/man/man1/php-config.1.gz
    File listed twice: /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
    File listed twice: /usr/share/man/man1/phpize.1.gz
```

I have no idea where I'm going wrong in my spec file. I can't find any duplicate entries anywhere in it. So I'm hoping if I can show you my spec file, you may be able to point out, how I'm going wrong.

```
Name:           php
Version:        5.6.7
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        PHP is a widely-used general-purpose scripting language.

Group:          Development/Languages
License:        PHP License v3.01
URL:            http://www.php.net
Source0:        http://www.php.net/distributions/php-%{version}.tar.bz2
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-buildroot

Obsoletes:      php

%description
PHP is a widely-used general-purpose scripting language that is especially
suited for Web development and can be embedded into HTML.

%prep
%setup -q -n %{name}-%{version}
%build
EXTENSION_DIR=%{_libdir}/php/modules; export EXTENSION_DIR
%configure --with-layout=GNU --with-libdir=lib64 --with-enchant \
--enable-fpm --with-gd --enable-intl --enable-mbstring --enable-pcntl \
--enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-sqlite-utf8 --enable-zip --with-zlib \
--with-curl --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-zlib-dir --with-gettext \
--with-mcrypt --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-    mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-pdo-sqlite --with-tidy --with-pear=%{_datadir}/php/pear --disable-debug

make %{?_smp_mflags}

%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_initrddir}
install -Dp -m0755 sapi/fpm/init.d.php-fpm.in %{buildroot}%{_initrddir}/php-fpm
%{__make} install INSTALL_ROOT="%{buildroot}"

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}

%post
%/sbin/chkconfig php-fpm on

%preun
if [ "$1" = 0 ] ; then
    /sbin/service php-fpm stop > /dev/null 2>&
    /sbin/chkconfig --del php-fpm
fi
exit 0

%postun
if [ "$1" -ge 1 ]; then
    /sbin/service php-fpm condrestart > /dev/null 2>&
fi
exit 0

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%{_bindir}/*
%{_sbindir}/*
%{_includedir}/*
%{_libdir}/*
%{_mandir}/man1/php*
%{_sysconfdir}/*
%{_datadir}/*
%{_initrddir}/*
%exclude /.channels
%exclude /.depdb
%exclude /.depdblock
%exclude /.filemap
%exclude /.lock

%changelog
* Mon Mar 23 2015 Mike Willbanks <mike @_________.com> - 5.3.8-1
- Updated to 5.3.8
* Mon Mar 23 2015 Mike Willbanks </mike><mike @_________.com> - 5.3.5-1
- Initial Package
```

Can someone please offer some advice on how to get this right?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Try http://serverfault.com, you'll probably get a better response.

Comment: The symlink is the only real problem. The "files listed twice" can be ignored.